# How can I make a UIView to appear on all my app Screens as long as it is visible iOS objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building a music application i want a view to show on all the screens in my objective-c ios app, above the Tab bars (all the screens of all the tab items) when the app is currently playing a song or a song is only paused. Similar to the iPhone/iPad music app as shown in the image below:
[image: iPad music app]

Answer (score 1):

You can add your view directly to the `UITabBarController`'s view.

`[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:musicPlayerView];`

This way it will be visible in all your Tabs.

Just an addition, it would be a better approach to subclass `UITabBarController` and initialize / add the musicPlayerView in your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Use UINavigation controller and it will last forever as you need.